# Google Spreadsheet script: How to write variable into a specific field?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a little script which calculates a specific date. Lets call the variable just "x".
Then I have a google spreadsheet with different tables. Lets call the first table "Example 1" and the other table "Example 2".

What I want to do now is when I run the function of my little script that the variable is written into the Field B4 of the Table "Example 1".

How can I do that?

The calculated Date is correct and it is a string. I just need to know how to get this thing into the Field "B4" of the table "Example 1"

Comment: So you wrote a script. Why don't you share this little script. Most probably you need to create a menu item to activate the script....

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Example 1");
sheet.getRange("B4").setValue(x);
```